# Selecting sorted value from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I'm working with the following MySQL table with joomla.

```
id   |   Parent_id
7049 |   7051
0    |   7052
7051 |   7053
0    |   7054
7054 |   7055
```

I want select data from table in following way: parent ID followed by child ID. Is it is possible?
I have attached Image of table structure.
[image: Table structure]

Comment: Dat code formatting tho

Comment: Can you share what you have tried and tell us why it didn't work?

Comment: i,m trying to display hierarchy of the article which is store in database with parent id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a query like this:

```
SELECT id, parent_id
FROM tablename
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN parent_id=0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END,
  id
```